# Posting infomation in a textbox to another textbox on a different solution

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

Here is what I need to do (in ASP.NET):

Solution A, Project A, Page A will have a textbox and a link that opens up another page. This other page is part of Solution B, Project B, Page B. Page B will have a textbox and a submit button. When you click submit it will close the window returning to Page A placing the text that was in the textbox on Page B into another textbox on Page A.

I could probably store the value of the textbox into SQL Server and then retrieve it, but I was hoping there was another, better way.

Any help will be extremely helpful, thanks.

Using the following: ASP.NET, C#, JavaScript, jQuery, SQL Server, HTML, CSS, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that they are on two different domains?

Comment: Same domain. For example: http://www.sitenamehere.com/solutions/project1/page1.aspx? -> http://www.sitenamehere.com/solutions/project2/page1.aspx?

Comment: You can communicate between the two windows via JavaScript. If you open the window with `window.open` you can communicate via `window.opener` with the parent window.

Comment: based on your comment, if they are in the same domain, you can handle it with cookies.

Comment: If the pages need to share data like that, they really shouldn't be in separate projects (this of course assumes you have control over this--disregard if not the case).  If they were in the same project, you could convert one of them into a User Control that could just be nested inside the first page.

Comment: I have no control over where the projects are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use a jQuery modal window to display Page B and have a trigger within page B to send the data back to the element on page A

Page A:

```
<div id="page_a">
    <form>
        <input name="page_a_box" id="page_a_box">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="container_for_page_b">
</div>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'page_b.asp'
    ,cache: false
    ,dataType: 'html'
    ,success: function(data){
        // fill the container with html data
        $('#container_for_page_b').html(data);

        // invoke jQuery UI's dialogue window
        $('#container_for_page_b').dialog();
    }
});


</script>
```

Page B:

```
<div id="page_b">
    <form onSubmit="$('#page_a_box').val($('#page_b_box').val()); $('#container_for_page_b').dialog('destroy');">
        <input name="page_b_box" id="page_b_box">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Check this out for more ideas:
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily achieve this by using query parameter's.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I think he means like storing it in a table and then retrieving it on original page. That is a possibility, but I already knew that.

Answer (score 0):

On `Page B`, during the `Click` event of the button, set a Session variable:

```
Session["TextBoxB"] = textBoxB.Text;
```

and then on `Load` in `Page A`, add the code to look for it:

```
if (Session["TextBoxB"] != null)
{
    // it has a value so use it
    textBoxA.Text = Session["TextBoxB"];
}
```

Comment: @user2642212, can you elaborate on why?